# Standard deviation for the difference of two dataframes with group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, grouping, standard-deviation

I have two panda DataFrames:

Dataframe Yahoo:

```
date        ticker  return
2017-01-03  CRM     0.018040121229614625
2017-01-03  MSFT    -0.0033444816053511683
2017-01-04  CRM     0.024198086662915008
2017-01-04  MSFT    -0.0028809218950064386
2017-01-05  CRM     -0.0002746875429199269
2017-01-05  MSFT    0.0017687731146487362
```

Dataframe Quandl:

```
date        ticker  return
2017-01-03  CRM     0.018040120991250852
2017-01-03  MSFT    -0.003344466975803595
2017-01-04  CRM     0.024198103213211475
2017-01-04  MSFT    -0.0028809268004892363
2017-01-05  CRM     -0.00027464144673694513
2017-01-05  MSFT    0.0017687829680113065
```

I would like to get the standard deviation for the difference of Yahoo’s and Quandl’s 'return' data calculated across all ticker symbols for each day and data field.

How can I get that?

Comment: Is standard deviation calculated by grouping all dates for each ticker? Or do you expect just a single number from this process?

Comment: Subtract one from the other while grouping by  ticker (and date?) then get the stddev of the result. Or make a multiindex with date and ticker then subtract ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Start by merging the data:

- `df1` is Yahoo data
- `df2` is Quandl data

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date', 'ticker'], suffixes=('_yahoo', '_quandl'))
```

### Create `diff`:

```
df['diff'] = df.return_yahoo - df.return_quandl
```

### Output `df`:

[image]

### Get `std` of `ticker`:

```
df.groupby('ticker')['diff'].std()

ticker
CRM     2.345815e-08
MSFT    1.018375e-08
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```